# I want to extract the part of html that lies between my given conditions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a long html file and I want to extract a part of the html that lies between my given conditions.

```
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="justify">
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; TEXT-DECORATION: underline">ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS</font></font></div>

    ---
    ---
    ---
    ---
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="justify">
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; TEXT-DECORATION: underline">ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED STAFF COMMENTS</font></font></div>
```

There is a lot of html above, between and below these two snippets. I want to extract the html where it starts from **ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS** and end it at **ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED STAFF COMMENTS**

This is what I tried so far, but it only prints the html containing ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

for item in page_soup.find_all('font'):
    if "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS" in item.text:
            print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a boolean outside your for loop to keep track of if you want to print the lines or not. Something like:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

should_print = False
for item in page_soup.find_all('font'):
    if "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS" in item.text:
            should_print = True
    if "ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED STAFF COMMENTS" in item.text:
            break
    if should_print:
            print(item)
```